# Richfaces: limit rich:comboBox to values of the value list

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I've got the following simple comboBox in my page.

```
<rich:comboBox value="#{groupConfig.group}"
               styleClass="userCombo"
               filterNewValues="false"
               directInputSuggestions="true">
  <f:selectItems value="#{
    workflowConfigCtrl.groupsFor(groupConfig,appNode.approvalTier)
  }" />
</rich:comboBox>
```

It works marvellously, but sadly it allows input of values that are not part of the suggestionList (which makes sense, as I enabled direct text input.

I want direct text input enabled, so that the user can use the suggestion list to quick filter (from a huge group list which can comprise several 100 groups).

At the same time i don't want the user to enter a value that is not in the list. The current approach checks when the user saves the whole form. Is there any way to limit it earlier?

I tried to do it using a javascript onblur=  handler, but i can't find the place where the selectItem list is saved in the dom.

Comment: Why don't you just use `<rich:suggestionbox>`?

Comment: I want the ability to have a drop-down-box to select groups from, only with the shortcut of being able to search and prefilter. Using a textfield and a suggestionbox doesn't yield that automatically ( i could attach a button; okay.)   But also the suggestionbox is using ajax instead of a prerendered list, i think i don't want the lag in this case.

Comment: @user1442158 could you provide comment towards whether or not the answer I gave was useful?

Comment: Of course, i was off for the weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the comboBox list in javascript by using

```
#{rich:component('myComboBoxId')}.comboList.itemsText
```

and/or

```
#{rich:component('myComboBoxId')}.comboList.itemsValue
```

and then use `jQuery.inArray()` to verify if the item is in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access this combo box in the DOM by specifying its ID like in the following example.

```
<rich:comboBox value="#{groupConfig.group}"
               id="UniqueID"
               styleClass="userCombo"
               filterNewValues="false"
               directInputSuggestions="true">
  <f:selectItems value="#{
    workflowConfigCtrl.groupsFor(groupConfig,appNode.approvalTier)
  }" />
</rich:comboBox>
```

You could then use `document.getElementById("UniqueID")` to access it in the DOM.

Comment: its easy to access the combobox (which is in fact a <input type="text">) from javascript. but i need access to the *list* that is held by the rich component which renderes the suggestions/selection list, and i haven't found access to it yet. 
So yes, you're right about accessing the input element, but i asked how to access the list held behing it ( technically the javascript side of <f:selectItems> )